# SpringXD -> twitterstream --follow: ending with Http error

Tags: spring-xd, twitter-streaming-api

I'm trying to crate a stream that should follow @BBCBreaking (what should have 5402612 twitter ID), but I keep getting following Http error:

```
2016-03-28T02:13:12+0200 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ZKStreamDeploymentHandler - Deployment status for stream 'mystream': DeploymentStatus{state=deployed}
2016-03-28T02:13:13+0200 1.3.1.RELEASE WARN twitterSource-1-1 twitter.TwitterStreamChannelAdapter - Http error, waiting for 5 seconds before restarting
2016-03-28T02:13:19+0200 1.3.1.RELEASE WARN twitterSource-1-1 twitter.TwitterStreamChannelAdapter - Http error, waiting for 10 seconds before restarting
2016-03-28T02:13:30+0200 1.3.1.RELEASE WARN twitterSource-1-1 twitter.TwitterStreamChannelAdapter - Http error, waiting for 20 seconds before restarting
```

my stream command is:

```
stream create --name mystream --definition "twitterstream --follow='5402612' | log" --deploy
```

running on SpringXD: 1.3.1.RELEASE
please, any idea that why the error?

Comment: Try enabling DEBUG logging - log config is in the `xd/config` folder in `.groovy` files.

Comment: sorry I'm new to SpringXD,..how can I do that? I can see the xd-singlenode-logback.groovy file,...do I need to edit it or somehow run it with my stream?

Comment: Yes, set the loggers for `org.springframework.integration` and `org.springframework.xd`, `org.springframework.xd.dirt.server` to DEBUG and add a logger for `org.springframework.social.twitter` also at DEBUG. Or you can set all of `org.springframework` and comment out the more specific ones.

Comment: @GaryRussell please make this an answer.  I helped me immensely!

Comment: Done, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug such situations by enabling `DEBUG` logging - log config is in the `xd/config` folder in `.groovy` files; e.g. `xd-singlenode-logback.groovy`.

Set the loggers for `org.springframework.integration` and `org.springframework.xd`, `org.springframework.xd.dirt.server` to `DEBUG` and add a logger for `org.springframework.social.twitter` also at `DEBUG`.

Or you can set all of org.springframework and comment out the more specific ones.